# How can I show certain elements from an array based on a React State?

Tags: reactjs

I am a relatively new React developer, and I am attempting to show only certain services that have a serviceType of either exterior, interior, combo, or add on. As of now, I have mapped these services into a react component and I am able to display every service that I pull from my database. However, I would like to only display "exterior" services or "interior" services based on the user's selection.

My current code is as follows:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Service from './Service';
import OffersService from '../../../services/OffersService';
import Button from '../../UI/Button';

const ServiceList = props => {
    const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);
    const [service, setService] = useState('Exterior');

    const exteriorTypeHandler = () => {
        setService('Exterior');
    };

    const interiorTypeHandler = () => {
        setService('Interior');
    };

    const comboTypeHandler = () => {
        setService('Combo');
    };

    const addonsTypeHandler = () => {
        setService('Add Ons');
    };

    const offersList = offers.map(offer => (
        <Service
            key={offer.id}
            code={offer.serviceCode}
            name={offer.serviceName}
            description={offer.description}
            type={offer.serviceType}
            price={offer.salePrice}
        />
    ));

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllOffers();
    }, []);

    const getAllOffers = () => {
        OffersService.getAllServices()
            .then(response => {
                setOffers(response.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='flex justify-center space-x-4'>
                <Button name='Exterior' onClick={exteriorTypeHandler} />
                <Button name='Interior' onClick={interiorTypeHandler} />
                <Button name='Combos' onClick={comboTypeHandler} />
                <Button name='Add Ons' onClick={addonsTypeHandler} />
            </div>

            <ul>{offersList}</ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ServiceList;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In an attempt to get the results I'd like to see, I've tried the following code for my :

```js
<ul>
  {offersList.forEach(offer => {
        if (offer.serviceType === service) {
        return offer;
        }
  })}
</ul>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have also tried:
`{offersList.serviceType === service && <ul>{offersList}</ul>}`

I haven't been able to find anything to help in my Udemy lectures, YouTube, or other Stack Overflow posts, so I appreciate any help that can be given!

Comment: Can you give the response of 'getAllOffers' API call?

Comment: Yes of course `{
        "id": 1,
        "serviceCode": "Base-01",
        "serviceName": "Exterior Basic Clean",
        "description": "This is a basic exterior wash to help remove the day to day dirt that occurs during your routine drives. Foam, hand wash, and rinse of the complete exterior of your car. Includes a hand dry and all jams wiped.",
        "serviceType": "Exterior",
        "salePrice": "Starting at $45.00"
    },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<ul>
  {offers.map(offer => {
        if (offer.serviceType === service) {
            return <li> <Service
                         key={offer.id}
                         code={offer.serviceCode}
                         name={offer.serviceName}
                         description={offer.description}
                         type={offer.serviceType}
                         price={offer.salePrice}
    /> </li>;
        }
  })}
</ul>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You need to use map instead of forEach and return `offer` wrapped in `<li></li>` tag.

Comment: Mapping each offer on the offersList returns [object Object] and not the value that is in each index of the array.

Comment: Please also wrap `offer` in curly braces...sorry my bad for not noticing it earlier...Updated my answer

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting the issue of [object Object]... I'm going to keep messing around with it though

Comment: Updated my answer... Please have a look

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. Creating the Service Component in the list makes so much sense! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In my approach I used two state variables for `offers` and `filtered` services.

```
const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);
const [filteredServices, setfilteredServices] = useState();

const offersList = offers.map((offer) => (
<Service
  key={offer?.id}
  code={offer?.serviceCode}
  name={offer?.serviceName}
  description={offer?.description}
  type={offer?.serviceType}
  price={offer?.salePrice}
/>
));
```

When user select a particular service, filter the offers according to that and set the filteredServices.

```
const onClickTypeHandler = (e) => {
const currentService = e.target.name;
if (currentService === "Show All") { // If want to show all the offers set that.
  setfilteredServices(offers);
} else {   // filter the offers that matched for selected service.
  const filtered = offers.filter(
    (service) => service?.serviceName === currentService
  );
  console.log(filtered);
  setfilteredServices(filtered);
}
```

In display of the offers, show filtered or all the offers as below.

```
<ul>
      {filteredServices
        ? filteredServices.map((filteredService) => (
            <p>{filteredService.serviceName}</p>
          ))
        : offersList} // in 1st render, filteredServices empty. So display the all offers. then show filtered services.
    </ul>
  };
```

Check this [demo sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-chaplygin-k7eo5f?file=/src/App.js) for complete demonstration. Check this and share your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am assuming the `response.data` is being fetched successfully.  I like the approach but a little refactoring can be done.  First off, if all the `button` `names` are actual `serviceTypes` from the fetched data, then my solution should work.  Ideally, you want to use one `onClick` function for each `button` element.  In this case, we have something that can delineate from the other `Buttons` and that is their `name`.

So all we need to do is grab that name using `event` from the `onClick` handler (it looks like this in the code: `e.target.name`), save the name in our state for asynchronous filtering, and compare `offer.serviceType` to our `currentService` while looping through.  We use `map` instead of `forEach` because we need to actually allocate memory and display them in the DOM.

EDIT: Also, notice how I rendered the fetched data in `return`.  I used a `ternary operator` to make sure that the request was completed and the data stored in memory before we attempt to access it using `map`.  I forgot to the mention this too - if the `serviceTypes` from the database are not the matching the `names` on the `Buttons`, make sure to fix that for this to work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Service from './Service';
import OffersService from '../../../services/OffersService';
import Button from '../../UI/Button';

const ServiceList = props => {
    const [offers, setOffers] = useState([]);
    const [currentService, setCurrentService] = useState('')

    const onClickTypeHandler = (e) =>{
        console(e.target.name)
        setCurrentService(e.target.name)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllOffers();
    }, []);

    const getAllOffers = () => {
        OffersService.getAllServices()
            .then(response => {
                setOffers(response.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='flex justify-center space-x-4'>
                <Button name='Exterior' onClick={onClickTypeHandler} />
                <Button name='Interior' onClick={onClickTypeHandler} />
                <Button name='Combos' onClick={onClickTypeHandler} />
                <Button name='Add Ons' onClick={onClickTypeHandler} />
            </div>

            <ul>{offers ? offers.map(offer => {
                if (offer.serviceType === currentService){
                    return <li>        
                             <Service
                              key={offer.id}
                              code={offer.serviceCode}
                              name={offer.serviceName}
                              description={offer.description}
                              type={offer.serviceType}
                              price={offer.salePrice}
                             />
                          </li>
                }
            }) : ''}</ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ServiceList;
```

Comment: Thank you for your edits. I've applied them to my code, but I am still not receiving any data on the screen, so I added some log statements to see what is appearing. When the button is clicked, I am not receiving the value of name, and when the list is trying to iterate over the map, I am receiving `Offer is: [object Object]`. So, I guess I need to figure out why I'm not getting the value of the offer within the array.

Comment: Also for more visibility, my button component's code looks like this: 
`import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';

const Button = props => {
 return (
  <div>
   <button className='bg-slate-700 hover:bg-blue-700 px-10 py-2 rounded-md' onClick={props.onClick}>
    {props.name}
   </button>
  </div>
 );
};

export default Button;`

Comment: If ````offer```` is an object, that we should be able to go deeper to get what we need.  Please console.log offer.

Comment: Console.log(offer) is [object Object]

Comment: You're having trouble with the fetched object (I'm assuming JSON).  We need to see the structure of ````response.data```` or all these solutions are moot.

Comment: The answer from @Siddarth Seth works. I guess sending the object multiple times caused the issue of [object Object]

Comment: @Stephen All your above problems should be gone, also, I would suggest refactoring anyway.  You definitely don't want to have multiple click handlers in your code... it will be a nightmare to maintain as your app grows.

Comment: Most definitely. I figured out that the name value in my Button was located here --> `e.target.firstChild.nodeValue` so now I am able to only have 1 clickHandler to manager the service state. Again, thanks for your help!